# DataConnect error while trying to export from remote server

Tags: java, sql, jobs, dashdb, dataconnect

I have created several activities this month. Run many also with successfull results. Lately I've been experiencing some issues. Specifically the following one.

CDICO2024E: Batch of 1756 records could not be written to the data source: [SQLSTATE null] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.BatchUpdateException: [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.20.4] Batch failure. The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch.; Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null; [SQLSTATE 22001] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #496: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.20.4; [SQLSTATE 22001] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #509: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.20.4; [SQLSTATE 22001] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #527: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.20.4; [SQLSTATE 22001] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #528: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.20.4; [SQLSTATE 22001] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: Error for batch element #529: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.20.4

This activity exports data from 8 tables in remote server and loads in DB2 Warehouse on Cloud (ex dashdb). Does anyone understand the issue? It seems to be that an SQL sentence fails, but I am not sure what could be failing as I can't split the activity. I may try to export one by one and see if it works.

Any coment will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001 - Data being inserted into the database table column is larger than the assigned column length.

Comment: Thanks! I've modified the activity to recreate the table instead of replacing contect. It works that way solving the issue you state.